# Dockerizing a React App: The app starts inside the container, but it not accessible from the exposed port

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

This is a question specifically for the tutorial at: http://mherman.org/blog/2017/12/07/dockerizing-a-react-app/#.Wv3u23WUthF by **Michael Herman**

Problem: The app starts inside the container, but it is not accessible from the port I just exposed `-p 3000:3000`. When Browse to `localhost:3000` get a *This site can’t be reached* error

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  sample-app:
    container_name: sample-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
      - '/usr/src/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
```

**Dockerfile**

```
# base image
FROM node:9.6.1

# set working directory
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add `/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
# RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g --silent # Uncomment to silent logs
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g 

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]

#CMD tail -f /usr/src/app/README.md


###################################
# To Run sample app:
# docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app -v /usr/src/app/node_modules -p 3000:3000 --rm sample-app
```

**Docker logs** : https://docs.google.com/document/d/14LRCgjMLAkmdMiuedxAW2GWUAtxmWeJQCNQB2ezdYXs/edit

After running either the compose or single container. It shows successful startup, but nothing thereafter.

When I docker exec into the container, `$ curl localhost:3000` returns the proper index.html page

I start up the container with either:

```
$ docker run -it -v ${PWD}:/usr/src/app -v /usr/src/app/node_modules -p 3000:3000 --rm sample-app
```

<- (The image `sample-app` exists )

or

```
$ docker-compose up
```

Comment: What port is your application listening to?

Comment: 3000.
As I said above: when I docker exec into the container, `$ curl localhost:3000` returns the proper HTML page (index.html). This should prove that the app is up and running listening to `:3000`

Comment: try adding EXPOSE 3000 to your Dockerfile

Comment: Already tried `EXPOSE 3000`, no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After eliminating all other factors I assume that your application is listening on localhost. Localhost is scoped to the container itself. Therefore to be able to connect to it, you would have to be inside the container.

To fix this, you need to get your application to listen on 0.0.0.0 instead.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your are exposing the app on localhost strictly. 
You have to modify your `package.json` to change that:

```
"start": "http-server -a localhost -p 3000"
```

into:

```
"start": "http-server -a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000"
```

if your contents of `package.json` differ strongly from that what's above, the important part is the `-a` option - it has to point to `0.0.0.0` as it means the http-server will listen on all incoming connections.

If you are not sure what to change, just post the essential part of `package.json` here in your question so we can check it.

Comment: Ah you were, although I didn't want to remove my answer as I explained the solution in detail and hope the community will find my answer useful ;)

Comment: @LeonardCapacete @trust512 I wish they were both combined in one answer, each has a piece of info the other one is missing. As trust512 said, my server is different so I had to do instead:  `webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000` . Note that `-a 0.0.0.0 -p 3000` wont work for `webpack-dev-server`

Comment: You can always accept one (more pts) and upvote the other (less pts but still awarding) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using `create-react-app` but I managed to solve it by not exposing the docker port in the `Dockerfile` and running the following command `docker container run -p ANY_PORT_YOU_WANT:**3000** -d image_name`. It so happens that by default react-server runs on PORT 3000 in the docker container and by exposing any other port other than 3000, that connection flow is killed. The start script uses `0.0.0.0` by default. See [Issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3984)